# Saving 16bit raster to RGB PNG (or TIF) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, png, save

I was following this post here: [Converting Grayscale GeoTIFF to PNG using QGIS results in all black image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332234/converting-grayscale-geotiff-to-png-using-qgis-results-in-all-black-image/363919)

I don't want a grayscale but RGB PNG.
When I do Raster->translate and select byte I only get a white image.

Comment: Did you style the image? Then rightclick the raster in the layer window, choose export and change the topmost bulletpoint to "as displayed".

Comment: @Erik I don't know what style means, but I'll try that! thanks!!

Comment: Did you change the symbology (aka "style the image")?

Comment: @Erik I did try all the options there (in symbology)

Comment: So you displayed the image in RGB?

Comment: yes. Should I have done something differently?

Comment: Did you then export the image as displayed?

Comment: Yes, I got all white, I ended up using gdal. I thought QGIS might be easier :-).

Comment: QGIS is easier. I guess you went wrong somewhere. It'd be easier, to assess when and where, when looking over your shoulder.