# How to convert masked image in QGIS to PNG

Tags: qgis-3

I am trying to export my LULC masked image (classified) to PNG format. I tried this method
Raster > Conversion > Translate as said [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332234/converting-grayscale-geotiff-to-png-using-qgis-results-in-all-black-image). My masked image has been classified into 4 covers only, but when following the conversion steps (as shown in above steps) the range changed from 0-255, when I want it to be between 0-3.

[image]

Thane_2019_Composite -> Is my classified image in .tif

temp -> after converting to .png

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Once the image is a PNG the pixels no longer hold a classified 'value' per se, they are now a colour. The 0-255 is the greyscale value of each pixel.

Comment: @Matt So, are you saying if I want to further train this masked image in a Neural Network, I can safely keep my output layer as 4? This grayscale will not affect the classification?

Comment: If there is a crisp boundary between classifications in your PNG then it should still only hold 4 values, indeed.

Comment: Click some pixels in your PNG in QGIS using the Info tool and make sure they are the same values as the TIFF layer, and are only one band. PNGs are usually 3 band RGB images, but 1-band PNGs are valid.